# I am trying to build a function to fetch specific JSON values from multiple web pages in a Wikia

Tags: javascript, json

As stated in the question, I have a series of JSON tags that I would like to access from multiple "Servants" within this Wikia. An example of the API would be:

https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Abigail_Williams&rvprop=content&format=json

Would it be possible to build a URL string with const tags for each character name, and if so, how would that look? I tried the following with no success:

```
    const baseURL = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php';
let url;  
  
  url = baseURL + '&prop=revisions&titles=' + servantTitle.value + '&rvprop=content&format=json'; 
    const servantTitle = ('Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai','Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime)';
    const baseURL = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to loop through each item in servantTitle and create a url with the title value.

```
const baseURL = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php';
const servantTitle = ['Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai','Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime'];

let url;  
  
for (let title in servantTitle) {
    url = baseURL + '&prop=revisions&titles=' + servantTitle[title] + '&rvprop=content&format=json'; 
    console.log(url) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get your array of urls by servantTitle :-)

```js
const baseURL = 'https://fategrandorder.fandom.com/api.php';
const servantTitle = ['Artoria_Pendragon', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Alter)', 'Artoria_Pendragon_(Lily)', 'Nero_Claudius', 'Siegfried', 'Gaius_Julius_Caesar', 'Altera', 'Gilles_de_Rais_(Saber)', "Chevalier_d'Eon", 'Okita_Sōji', 'Fergus_mac_Róich', 'Mordred', 'Nero_Claudius_(Bride)', 'Ryōgi_Shiki_(Saber)', 'Rama, Water_Iri', 'Lancelot_Saber', 'Gawain', 'Bedivere', 'Elizabeth_Báthory_(Brave)', 'Miyamoto_Musashi', 'Arthur_Pendragon_(Prototype)', 'Suzuka_Gozen', 'Frankenstein_(Saber)', 'Yagyū_Munenori', 'Sigurd', 'Medb_(Saber)', 'Diarmuid_Ua_Duibhne', 'Lanling_Wang', 'Beni-enma', 'Lakshmibai','Jason', 'Katsushika_Hokusai_(Saber)', 'Astolfo_(Saber)', 'Dioscuri', 'Tomoe_Gozen_(Saber)', 'Saitō_Hajime'];

const URLs = servantTitle.map(servant =>
  `${baseURL}?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=${servant}&rvprop=content&format=json`
)

console.log(URLs)
```

Comment: Did you get the output and create a visualize data?